# Apply class if empty

Tags: jquery, css

I need to check whether an `img` `src` is empty and then apply a class to another element.

Here is the HTML

```
<span class="page-icon"><img src="" width="40" height="40" alt="Privacy" /></span>
```

If the img src is empty, apply the class `hide` to the `span.page-icon`.

Comment: What have you tried so far? jQuery has good documentation http://api.jquery.com/. I recommend to have a look at it.

Comment: The src attribute should never be empty for all sorts of reasons... http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/11/30/empty-image-src-can-destroy-your-site/, http://www.digital-media-lab.com/research_web_design_avoid_empty_image_src.html, etc

Comment: $('img[src=""]') selects all <img> having src="".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an attribute selector to get `img` elements with an empty src attribute.

```
$("img[src='']").parent().addClass("hide");
```

Answer (score 5):

```
$('img[src=""]').parent().addClass('hide')
```

Comment: What happens if there is an empty img tag that isn't inside a span with the class page-icon?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do it for all images on a page...

```
$('img').each(function(){
 var src = $(this).attr('src');
 if (!src){
  $(this).parent('.page-icon').addClass('hide');
 }
});
```

Comment: Why not this.src, dont use attr where you do ont need to.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('span.page-icon img').each(function() {
    console.log(this.src);
    if (this.src.length <= 0) {
        $(this).parent().addClass('hide');
    }
    else if ($(this).attr('src').length <= 0) {
        $(this).parent().addClass('hide');
    }
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/kk9MQ/

Answer (score 0):

```
$("img").each(function()
{

   if($(this).attr("src") === "")
   {

       $(this).parent().addClass("hide");

   }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('span').has('img[src=""]').addClass('hide');
```

Look for any `span` that has an `img` with `src=""` and add the class `hide`

Answer (score 0):

If the span will only contain a single image tag this will work:

```
$('span.page-icon:has(img[src=""])').addClass('hide');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Dhfam/

Answer (score -1):

This should work:

```
if ($(".page-icon img").attr("src").length == 0) {
  $(".page-icon").addClass("hide");
}
```

Comment: This will add the class hide to all elements with the class page-icon!

Comment: You're absolutely right, I was too quick to post my response. :)